# Unable to append multiple items inside user wishlist key

Tags: node.js, mongoose, frontend, backend, crud

**This is my frontend code. Initially i took user from token were token is present in local storage, then code for updating user and the fetch to get user in database updated.**

```
     let token = JSON.parse (localStorage.getItem ('token'));
        
        async function addtoWishlist (id) {
          let temp = await findId ();
          let user = await temp.json ();
          let wishlistArray = user.wishItems;
          console.log ('wishlistArray:', wishlistArray);
        
          wishlistArray.push (id);
          let dts = {
            wishItems: wishlistArray,
          };
          let data_to_send = JSON.stringify (dts);
        
          fetch (`http://localhost:2233/*/user/add`, {
            method: 'PATCH',
            body: data_to_send,
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          })
            .then (k => {
              return k.json ();
            })
            .then (res => {
              console.log (res);
            })
            .catch (err => {
              console.log (err);
            });
        }
        
        async function findId () {
          let user = await fetch (`http://localhost:2233/*/user`, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          });
        
          return user;
        }
```

**contoller code**

```
app.get ('/*/user', authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user.user;

  return res.send (user);
});

app.patch ('/*/user/add', authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log ('inside patch');

    let user = req.user.user;
    console.log ('user:', user);
    console.log (req.body);

    user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate (user._id, req.body, {
      new: true,
    })
      .lean ()
      .exec ();
    console.log ('after-user', user);
    return res.send (user);
  } catch (e) {
    return res.send (e.message);
  }
});
```

**User schema is shown below**

```
const userSchema = new Schema (
  {
    fullName: {type: String, required: false},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    mobile: {type: Number, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    bagItems: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'product',
          required: false,
        },
        count: {type: Number, required: false},
      },
    ],
    wishItems: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

** whenever i add item to wishlist, it replaces the item which is already present............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................**

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [$push operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

```
user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate (user._id, { $push: req.body }, { ...
```

Make sure the `req.body` only has `wishItems` property nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to accept my answer ;)